# Visual Basic Print Preview Dialog Table

Tags: vb.net, printing

I'm trying to open a print preview Dialog in VB.net (2012). I know how to open the print preview dialog, and how to add stuff tot the document.

My question however is, how do I print a table to the Document?

Currently all the guides I find on the internet, just don't help at all.

My current Code:

```
Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(sender As Object, e As Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles     Document.PrintPage
    Dim text As String = strTable

    Dim printFont As New System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 16, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular)
    e.Graphics.DrawString(text, printFont, System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, 0, 0)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up your columns manually and iterate through the rows.

For this example, assume that strTable contains a string with tabs delimiting each column, and carriage return, line feeds separating rows.  You would parse the string into rows and columns, and place them

```
Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) _
Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage

    #this is an example string I used to test the routine.
    Dim strTable = "1 Col one" & vbTab & "col two" & vbTab & "col three" & vbCrLf &
             "2 Col one" & vbTab & "col two" & vbTab & "col three" & vbCrLf &
             "3 Col one" & vbTab & "col two" & vbTab & "col three" & vbCrLf
    #This creates a string array containing each row of our table
    Dim Rows() As String = Split(strTable, vbCrLf)
    #this will keep track of our vertical position on the paper
    Dim Row_Position As Single = 0
    #This is where each column will be on the page, horizontally
    Dim Column_Positions() As Single = {0, 100, 200}
    Dim printFont As New System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 16, _
    System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular)
    'Get the height of a row.  I'm taking the height of a 'W' and adding a bit.
    #Measurestring  returns a Double which needs to be converted to single
    Dim RowHeight As Single = CType(e.Graphics.MeasureString("W", printFont).Height * 1.25, Single)

    For Each aRow In Rows
        #Now, we split our row up into columns
        Dim cols() As String = Split(aRow, vbTab)

        #and just iterate through the columns, putting them where they need to be
        For idx = 0 To cols.Length - 1
            e.Graphics.DrawString(cols(idx), printFont, _
            System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, _
            e.MarginBounds.Left + Column_Positions(idx), _
            e.MarginBounds.Top + Row_Position)
        Next
        Row_Position += RowHeight
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: It actually prints without an issue to the document. I'd like to draw a Table, and Print tot he Table.

Comment: When I have done this, I used measurestring to make sure that the columns didn't overlap.  If the string didn't fit (I used measurestring.width) and scale the font size accordingly